# How to access the original case sensitive username input in custom user storage provider of keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

I need to integrate keycloak with an existing application. Users log in with username and password. Unfortunately, the application supports case-sensitive usernames and must continue to do so.

When creating the Custom User Storage Provider, at the entry point `public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm)` I get the username, but it has already been converted to a case insensitive String.

Here is an example which illustrates the situation.

| username input | received username | users in database |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | john doe | john doe, John Doe |

I am aware that keycloak does not support case sensitive users, but for retrieving the users from the database I need to be able to distinguish the users. Is it possible to access the original input of the username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like you noticed correctly, usernames (and also email) are converted to lowercase in Keycloak. This behaviour is introduced by the [`UserCacheSession`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/bfce612641a70e106b20b136431f0e4046b5c37f/model/infinispan/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/cache/infinispan/UserCacheSession.java#L243)-class. The only way i found to get around this is to disable user caching globally in the Keycloak instance. This can be done by setting the appropriate configuration values inside `standalone.xml`, `standalone-ha.xml` or `domain.xml` (depending on your setup like described [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_installation/topics/cache/disable.html)).

The config block should be changed from

```xml
<spi name="userCache">
    <provider name="default" enabled="true"/>
</spi>
```

to

```xml
<spi name="userCache">
    <provider name="default" enabled="false"/>
</spi>
```

You can also use the JBoss CLI for this. If you're using a docker based setup, this could look like the following.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
USER root
COPY disable-usercache.cli /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/disable-usercache.cli
USER 1000
```

`disable-usercache.cli`:

```bash
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
batch

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userCache/provider=default/:write-attribute(name=enabled,value=false)

run-batch
stop-embedded-server
```

If you need further samples you can have a look [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html/server_installation_and_configuration_guide/manage_subsystem_configuration).

If you've disabled the usercache, the `username` variable should be passed as given by the user.

**Please note:** of course you'll lose some performance if you turn of user caching because Keycloak will query the user storage each time a user has to be looked up. So it might be worth implementing your own case senisitive user cache and overwrite the default one by [updating the `userCache` SPI](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3ebfc91b75c3ca6c48bd54380fe4ffe891829aad/docs/updating-server-config.md#updating-an-spi) inside your servers configuration file.

**EDIT 03/2022:** since Keycloak 17 [is now powered by Quarkus](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#keycloak-17-0-0), the mentioned WildFly script `disable-usercache.cli` won't work anymore. Until June 2022 you could use the legacy WildFly powered distribution of Keycloak 17 or have a look at the [migration guide](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus) to see how to migrate towards Quarkus.

**EDIT 11/2022:** for Quarkus powered Keycloak instances, you'll have to locate the file `conf/cache-ispn.xml`. The default configuration contains a block for caching users like this:

```xml
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:11.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-11.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:11.0">
    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <!-- DELETE THIS BLOCK -->
        <local-cache name="users">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <!-- UNTIL HERE -->
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

Delete the appropriate block to disable the user cache. Read more about how to configure caching in the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching).