# Duplcated of How to access the original case sensitive username input in custom user storage provider of keycloak?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, lowercase, keycloak-spi

I developed a service provider interface (SPI) for User Federation in keycloak.

When I try to login with an existing case sensitive user, keycloak converts it to lower case, so at the end, the sent username was not found in my user API.

I am using keycloak 20.0.1 version and it is deploying in a docker container.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553369/how-to-access-the-original-case-sensitive-username-input-in-custom-user-storage) post in stackoverflow that share an anwerd relatated for this, buth I do not get solution. I replaced `conf/cache-ispn.xml` as it metion, buth when keycloak starts it gets the error `Cache 'users' has been requested, but no matching cache configuration exists`.

I realy apreciate if some one knows if there is an alternative.

Regardles.

I tried to get original input username with case sensitive in keycloak login.

Comment: Have you managed to modify the keycloak server to be case sensitive? If so can you share the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution mentioned on that post about removing the cache configuration from `cache-ispn.xml` but it doesn't work at least not in the version i'm using - 22.0.3 - I need the case sensitive username to delegate the autentication to another service. I found that the problem is within a class `UserCacheSession` which runs before my customization and converts the username to lowercase. As a workaround I write my own Cache SPI Customization that I inherit from the default implementation (infinispan), basically I wrote a class like this:

```
class CustomUserCacheProviderFactory extends InfinispanUserCacheProviderFactory {
    @Override
    public UserCache create(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.lazyInit(session);
        return new CustomUserCache(this.userCache, session);
    }
```

Which creates a CustomCache that inherits from the default implementation too:

```
public class CustomUserCache extends UserCacheSession {
    @Override
    public UserModel getUserByUsername(RealmModel realm, String username) {
        MemoryCache.getInstance().put(username.toLowerCase(), username);
        return super.getUserByUsername(realm, username);
    }
}
```

There I created my own `MemoryCache` which is a key-value store where I save the original username so I can get it where I need without interfering with what Keycloak does internally.